# I get different value in recursion for knapsack problem

Tags: java, recursion, knapsack-problem

I wrote two pieces of code for knapsack problem. The first code gives me the correct answer (which is 16) and the second one doesn't. Is it something wrong with my recursive function?

First code (correct answer):

```java
public class knapsackProblem {

    static int[] weight = {1,2,4,2,5};
    static int[] value = {5,3,5,3,2};
    int result = 0;

    // recursive function
    public int sack(int i, int cap) 
    {
        //base case
        if(i<0 || cap == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        } else if(weight[i] > cap)
        {
            return sack(i-1, cap);
        } else
        {
            //get maximum value
            return Math.max(sack(i-1, cap), value[i] + sack(i-1, cap - weight[i]));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int capacity = 10;
        int len = weight.length;
        knapsackProblem kp = new knapsackProblem();
        int total = kp.sack(len - 1, capacity);
        System.out.println("sacked array is " + total);
    }

}
```

Second code (incorrect answer):

```java
public class knapsackProblem {

    static int[] weight = {1,2,4,2,5};
    static int[] value = {5,3,5,3,2};
    int result = 0;
    int tempNO = 0;
    int tempYES = 0;

    // recursive function
    public int sack(int i, int cap) 
    {
        //base case
        if(i<0 || cap == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        } else if(weight[i] > cap)
        {
            return sack(i-1, cap);
        } else
        {
            //no case, move on to next value
            tempNO = sack(i-1, cap);

            //yes case, add the current value and move on to next value with decreased capacity
            tempYES = value[i] + sack(i-1, cap - weight[i]);

            //get maximum value
            return Math.max(tempNO, tempYES);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int capacity = 10;
        int len = weight.length;
        knapsackProblem kp = new knapsackProblem();
        int total = kp.sack(len - 1, capacity);
        System.out.println("sacked array is " + total);
    }

}
```

The only difference is that in second code I put the results from recursion into variables before comparing for maximum value.

Thanks

Comment: your first code is also recursive. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables are attributes of the class. The recursive calls are modifying those attributes every time, because you're using one single instance of the class to make the calls to the function. Declare the variables inside the method and remove them from the class to make it work. :)